# How can fiat credits issued on the Stellar network be converted directly to fiat (without going through an exchange)?

Tags: transactions

When an anchor issues fiat credits on the Stellar Network, how can these credits be withdrawn directly to a bank account or as cash at an ATM?

For example, If I give 10 USD to an anchor and am issued 10 XUSD credits, then these 10 XUSD credits are transferred to another account, how does the receiving account withdraw those 10 XUSD credits for 10 USD? Wouldn't this require a partnership with a bank, and if so, have there been any banks that have implemented a withdrawal system like this?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to find an anchor that accepts XUSD for USD to cash out. That's likely the issuer of XUSD. Tempo.eu.com does this for example for EURT:

> To facilitate flow across the Stellar network TEMPO is issuing the EURT which can be traded for PHP, XLM, and the JPY on the Stellar Blockchain. Clients can use the EURT for trading or cash out to European bank accounts using SEPA. TEMPO and their various partners will value EURTs at full parity to the EUR. The token will have many functions including for remittance purposes or bill pay.

https://medium.com/tempomoneytransfer/tempo-launches-eurt-trading-on-the-programically-fair-stellar-distributed-exchange-1e6155c64454